# Build Docker Images without Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I want to build Docker images on Windows Server 2012. Is there a simple Windows tool that I can use just for building Docker images?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows) installs a Linux VM on your Windows host and you can build your images within that Linux VM if this is what you need...